# Exploding nested Struct in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, distributed-computing, databricks

I'm working through a Databricks example. The schema for the dataframe looks like:

```
> parquetDF.printSchema
root
|-- department: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
|-- employees: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- salary: integer (nullable = true)
```

In the example, they show how to explode the employees column into 4 additional columns:

```
val explodeDF = parquetDF.explode($"employees") { 
case Row(employee: Seq[Row]) => employee.map{ employee =>
  val firstName = employee(0).asInstanceOf[String]
  val lastName = employee(1).asInstanceOf[String]
  val email = employee(2).asInstanceOf[String]
  val salary = employee(3).asInstanceOf[Int]
  Employee(firstName, lastName, email, salary)
 }
}.cache()
display(explodeDF)
```

How would I do something similar with the department column (i.e. add two additional columns to the dataframe called "id" and "name")? The methods aren't exactly the same, and I can only figure out how to create a brand new data frame using:

```
val explodeDF = parquetDF.select("department.id","department.name")
display(explodeDF)
```

If I try:

```
val explodeDF = parquetDF.explode($"department") { 
  case Row(dept: Seq[String]) => dept.map{dept => 
  val id = dept(0) 
  val name = dept(1)
  } 
}.cache()
display(explodeDF)
```

I get the warning and error:

```
<console>:38: warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern Seq[String] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
            case Row(dept: Seq[String]) => dept.map{dept => 
                           ^
<console>:37: error: inferred type arguments [Unit] do not conform to    method explode's type parameter bounds [A <: Product]
  val explodeDF = parquetDF.explode($"department") { 
                                   ^
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use something like that:

```
var explodeDF = explodeDF.withColumn("id", explodeDF("department.id"))
explodeDeptDF = explodeDeptDF.withColumn("name", explodeDeptDF("department.name"))
```

which you helped me into and these questions:

- [Flattening Rows in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906613/flattening-rows-in-spark)
- [Spark 1.4.1 DataFrame explode list of JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068792/spark-1-4-1-dataframe-explode-list-of-json-objects)

Comment: A stage failure: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 41.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 41.0 (TID 1403, 10.81.214.49): scala.MatchError: [[789012,Mechanical Engineering]] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)

Comment: @Feynman27 does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222989/erasure-elimination-in-scala-non-variable-type-argument-is-unchecked-since-it) help? It seems to match *your* attempt. I think the problem with my answer is that the `employees` has also an element, while `department` has not.

Comment: Yeah, the `employees` example creates new rows, whereas the `department` example should only create two new columns.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008127/how-to-read-a-nested-collection-in-spark

Comment: Can we do this for all nested columns with renaming at once? For example, `department.id` -> `inner_id`, `department.name` -> `inner_name`, ...

Answer (score 50):

In my opinion the most elegant solution is to star expand a Struct using a select operator as shown below:

```
var explodedDf2 = explodedDf.select("department.*","*")
```

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/complex-types.html

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work (though maybe not the most elegant solution).

```
var explodeDF2 = explodeDF.withColumn("id", explodeDF("department.id"))
explodeDF2 = explodeDF2.withColumn("name", explodeDF2("department.name"))
```

Comment: you could `val explodeDF2 = explodeDF.withColumn("id", explodeDF("department.id")).withColumn("name", explodeDF2("department.name"))`