# iterating complex dataframe with array of structfield

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have data in one of dataframe's column with the following schema

```
<type 'list'>: [StructField(data,StructType(List(StructField(account,StructType(List(StructField(Id,StringType,true),StructField(Name,StringType,true),StructField(books,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(bookTile,StringType,true),StructField(bookId,StringType,true),StructField(bookName,StringType,true))),true),true)))))))]
```

I want to interate them extract each value out of it and create a new dataframe. Is there any inbuilt functions in pyspark supports this or I should iterate them? Any efficient way?

Comment: There is an `explode` function that will put each element of the array on its own row. Is that what you want?

Comment: I tried it but it gave me "due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not struct"

Comment: Ah, I may have missunderstood you. It would be a bit clearer if you can add an example input/expected output dataframe to the question. However, it could be that you are looking for how to expand a struct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753898/how-to-flatten-a-struct-in-a-spark-dataframe or maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275816/exploding-nested-struct-in-spark-dataframe