# Extract struct fields in Spark scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I have a df of schema

```
|-- Data: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- address_billing: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- address1: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- address2: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- address_shipping: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- address1: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- address2: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- cancelled_initiator: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- cancelled_reason: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- statuses: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |-- store_code: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- store_name: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- tax_code: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- total: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- updated_at: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to extract its all fields in separate columns without manually giving name.

Is there any way by which we can do this?
I tried:

```
val df2=df1.select(df1.col("Data.*"))
```

but got the error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field * in address_billing, address_shipping,....
```

Also, Can anyone suggest to me how to add a prefix to all these columns, as the some of the columns name may be the same.
Output should be like 
address_billing_address1
address_billing_address2
.
.
.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exploding nested Struct in Spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275816/exploding-nested-struct-in-spark-dataframe)

Comment: @mazaneicha `explode` is not required here. `Explode` requires only if nested structure is array.

Comment: @mazaneicha How to add the prefix to all these columns which we extracted out?

Answer (score 1):

Just change `df1.col` to `col`. Either of these should work:

```
df1.select(col("Data.*"))
```

```
df1.select($"Data.*")
```

```
df1.select("Data.*")
```

Comment: How to add the prefix to all these columns which we extracted out?